# Why do Facebook's JSONP callbacks start with "/**/"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, jsonp

When I used Facebook's Open Graph API, I noticed that the JSONP responses generated by Facebook seemed to have an extraneous "/**/" at the beginning of each response like this:

```
URL: 
https://graph.facebook.com/SOME_ID?method=get&pretty=0&sdk=joey&callback=FB.__globalCallbacks.f1c77f051c

Response:
/**/ FB.__globalCallbacks.f887adeec(...);
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We added this to protect against an attack where a third party site bypasses the content-type of the response by doing: <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://graph.facebook.com?callback=[specifically crafted flash bytes]"></object>

Google does something similar, except they use //... + \n (e.g. http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?alt=json&callback=foo)

Comment: Does that mean that flash accepts an SWF-like file with additional content at the end? (the API response)

Comment: Well, I've tested it and it seems that flash *does* accept additional bytes at the end of *uncompressed* SWF files.

Comment: [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#Rosetta_Flash) to the exploit, aka Rosetta Flash, apparently.  The vulnerability appears to be that the specially crafted flash bytes execute thinking that they are on the target site (facebook.com) and therefore get access to same-origin data (cookies, local storage, I presume) but can then send that information to the third-party.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly to prevent XSSI... so you can't execute it...

http://maxime.sh/2013/02/javascript-quest-ce-que-le-xssi-et-comment-leviter/&usg=ALkJrhhjfdwBrK7kxNipOowAYacIcJm89g">Here is a french blog post about that (with google translate)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent XSSI
look into the graph of facebook for more help
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/overview/

Comment: Perhaps give more specific snippets instead of just linking?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like Facebook is using a scrubber on their JSON, and it's just leaving the remaining comment holder at the beginning. Most likely leave comments there for debugging purposes, but in production the actual comments are scrubbed.